# how to post a http request from command line

Tags: asp.net, http, command-line

Hi 
I need to post a request to aspx page within dos command line.. How can I do that ?

Comment: When you say post an http request, do you actually mean an HTTP POST, or do you just mean request a web page like any ol' browser would do (HTTP GET)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a .vbs file containing:

```
' Set your settings
    strFileURL = "http://localhost/index.aspx"
    strHDLocation = "stream.temp"

' Fetch the file
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
    objXMLHTTP.send()

If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objADOStream.Open
objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start

Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation

objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
objADOStream.Close
Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

' Delete the temp file
objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation

Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Then execute using:

```
cscript.exe scriptname.vbs
```

Answer (score 20):

telnet on port 80

For example:

```
telnet www.your-server.com/pageToTest.aspx 80
```

then type `GET`

Comment: I'm getting `C:\Windows\system32>telnet
'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: You can activte telenet package by typing these two command ,then after restart your computer and all  will be fine !

<br/>pkgmgr /iu:TelnetClient
<br/>pkgmgr /iu:TelnetServer

Comment: More information: http://www.esqsoft.com/examples/troubleshooting-http-using-telnet.htm

Comment: Telnet server is not needed (and is pretty much never recommended) in order to use the telnet command

Answer (score 16):

All of these answers require installing a windows feature or other program. Powershell is installed by default and can be run from the command line

```
powershell -command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri %url% -Method POST"
```

Comment: Is not work on Windows 7 using powershell.

Comment: Works on Windows 10

Comment: Invoke-WebRequest only comes standard since Powershell 5.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using [`wget`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

Comment: Could you elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 3):

I've had some good luck with cURL http://curl.haxx.se/ to replicate sending JSON to a webservice. Perhaps this might help you too.

Answer (score 2):

This works on Windows 10

```bash
powershell -command "Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Method POST -Uri http://example.com/login -Body username=exampleuser'&'password=test"
```

More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 1):

Telnet is really for connecting to a remote telnet server. In fact it (telnet server) is not present in Windows 10, only the client.
You better use PowerShell. Here is an example accessing ODATA service:
[http://hodentekhelp.blogspot.com/2014/11/can-you-access-odata-with-powershell.html](https://hodentekhelp.blogspot.com/2014/11/can-you-access-odata-with-powershell.html)

Also review this thread:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/035062dd-5052-4abe-bd9a-8714f4184806/there-is-no-telnet-server-in-windows-10-what-is-the-purpose-of-telnet-client?forum=win10itprogeneral

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use wget which is a common command line tool (v useful for downloading). On windows you can get it from here http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm and its already part of most Linux distros. To use simply do the following;-

```
wget google.com
```

and that will return the following

```
--2018-03-20 16:31:39--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com... 216.58.204.14
Connecting to google.com|216.58.204.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=dzexWqybGof38Afo3ZmACg [following]
--2018-03-20 16:31:39--  http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=dzexWqybGof38Afo3ZmACg
Resolving www.google.co.uk... 216.58.201.3
Connecting to www.google.co.uk|216.58.201.3|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html@gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=dzexWqybGof38Afo3ZmACg'

    [ <=>                                                                                                                                                                                                 ] 12,441      --.-K/s   in 0s

2018-03-20 16:31:40 (88.3 MB/s) - `index.html@gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=dzexWqybGof38Afo3ZmACg' saved [12441]
```