# Trigger Jenkins job only via API

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Is it possible to trigger a jenkins job only via Jenkins' remote API?

I want that job triggered remotely by a script. That's because the script takes care of test data setup. But sometimes someone triggers the job via the web frontend which results in a failure because of missing test data.

So how can I forbid anyone from triggering the build via the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, the solution is here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8512956/68969), depending on what you mean by script you will need to issue a post command from the command line (you don't say if you are using Windoes or *nix) details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277375/68969).

> how can I forbid anyone from triggering the build via the frontend?

Enable security and disable the build or all builds depending on your set up [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094269/how-to-block-some-jobs-for-some-user-level-in-jenkins/21096952#21096952)

Comment: There isn't a solution that doesn't require administrative rights on jenkins, is there?

Comment: @Fynn for which part, the API call will depend on your security settings - I don't think you need admin rights.  To change the build settings - you will need right for the job(s) but not necessary admin rights it will depend on your security settings

Comment: The API call is of no concern right now, that's working just fine. However, as a normal developer I don't have access to anything regarding Managing Jenkins..